# Power BI Rest API Requests Not Authorizing as expected

Tags: python, api, powerbi

I have built a python application to access read only Power BI Rest API’s.  I am automating the collection of tenant activity.  However despite configuring my Azure App and using the service principal to generate an access token, the response I receive from the API request is one of an unauthorised response:

```
{"error": {"code": "PowerBINotAuthorizedException", "pbi.error": {"code": 
"PowerBINotAuthorizedException", "parameters": {}, "details": [], "exceptionCulprit": 1}}}
```

I have found a number of similar issues posted online, however feel that I have done everything that is suggested but am still not able to get it working.  I would appreciate any guidance.

The steps that I have taken are:

1. Configured an Azure App, adding the Application Permission for Power Bi Service-Tenant.Read.All

   [Screenshot of App Settings in Azure Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iymGi.png)
2. Requested my access token based upon the Client Credentials Flow using my app's client_ID and client_Secret as documented in the below link:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

I successfully receive a token using the script below:

```
import requests

azureTenantID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
azureClientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
azureClientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

url = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{azureTenantID}/oauth2/v2.0/token"

payload = {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "client_id": azureClientId, 
        "client_secret": azureClientSecret,
        "scope": "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default"            
}
# Header HAS to be x-www-form-urlencoded for MS to accept it.
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

# Return POST content as JSON.
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers).json()

# Grab the access token.
response = r.get("access_token")

# Concatenate with Bearer string
access_token = "Bearer {r['access_token']}"
```

3. Configured my Power BI Tenant Settings to enable Service Principals to use API's.
   [Screenshot of Admin API Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kBDW.png)
   [Screenshot of Developer API Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ADLl.png)
   Note that I added the Service Principal as a member of the Security Group for which both of these settings are enabled
4. Execute my Get request to the API

The followings script returns a good response when I take an access token from the Power BI REST API Documentation's 'Try it out' feature, but not when I generate the token as above.

```
import requests

# Initialise parameters.
url = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/groups?$top=1000&$expand=datasets,dataflows,reports,users,dashboards"
headers = {'Authorization': get_access_token2()}

# Get response.
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
response = response.json()
```

Any assistance would be appreciated !

Comment: Did you add the Service Principal to your `pbig-ServicePrincipalAllowAPI` Security Group in AAD?  Does the code work if you generate an access token for yourself?

Comment: I just went through this and had to actually engage MS support for it. Decode your JWT and check and see if you receive any values in the 'roles' name/value pair. You should be getting nothing. It was explained to us as the roles override the service principal behaviour so if you get a role (based on your auth token) then you will get the "PowerBINotAuthorizedException" exception when you attempt to call the Power BI API using that token/service principal. If you aren't sure how to check you can use https://www.jstoolset.com/jwt and just paste your auth token.

Comment: David, yes I did add the Service principal to that security group. And yes if I generate an access token myself and hardcode it it everything works perfectly.

Comment: Cheers Trenton, if I have understood correctly, the key names of the JWT are ['token_type', 'expires_in', 'ext_expires_in', 'access_token'].  There is no 'roles' key.

Comment: You are talking about the other keys in the json in the actual http response (besides access_token). I am talking about the json that you get when you decode your token.

Comment: To be more clear, you need to take the value of your 'access_token' which is your JWT token, and decode it to look at its contents. You can do that by pasting your 'access_token' value to the 'JWT Token' section of https://www.jstoolset.com/jwt website and then looking in the 'Explanation' for the key/value pairs. If there is a role present with a value then that means your service prinicipal will try to use that role instead of simply attempting to follow the service principal path for auth in to that API, which results in the exception you provided.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now...I have decoded it and yes there is one value alongside role. It is Tenant.Read.All which is actually exactly how I had configured the Service Principal so I assume this means there is no conflict here

Comment: If there is any role there, then your service principal auth to the Power BI API will not work. So the fact that you see Tenant.Read.All, which matches to the permissions you added, is a problem. Try removing those permissions and then check to see if the role is gone from your token. If not, we resolved (for testing) by creating a new app with no allocated permissions and then added to same AD group to do this. Once there are no roles in your JWT token (for the service principal auth), then it should work.

Comment: Okay everything is now working. Thanks for your advice Trenton.  To summarize for anyone reading this...you should ensure you do all the steps that I did laid out in my question EXCEPT providing API Permissions to the App (Tenant.Read.All in my case).  It seems counter intuitive but if you provide Power BI API Permissions to the App, it will not work.  It seems whether an Application Service Principal is allowed to access the Power BI Rest APIs is managed in the Power BI Tenant Settings, and not the App Permissions.

Comment: @NickHall absolutely. I will go ahead and post as an answer for future readers.

Answer (score 3):

I just went through this exact scenario that you described, and in the end we had to engage Microsoft support to solve it.

Although extremely counter intuitive, **if the app that you create for your service principal authentication has any Power BI permissions assigned to it then the access token that is generated (when passed to Power BI REST Admin API) will return an error response that reports `PowerBINotAuthorizedException`**.

**To be even more specific**, if the access token that you pass to the Power BI API has a `roles` key/value pair, then you will get a `PowerBINotAuthorizedException`.

In your case, the issue is easier because you have listed out what permissions you granted. You mentioned that you `Configured an Azure App, adding the Application Permission for Power Bi Service-Tenant.Read.All`. **In order to resolve this issue, you will need to remove that permission.**

For future readers, you can troubleshoot this by decoding your access token using a JWT token decoder like one found at [jstoolset.com](https://www.jstoolset.com/jwt). If your app has permissions allocated to the scope that you have requested (https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default is the typical Power BI scope that you request in your authorization) and you decode your JWT token then you will see a `roles` key/value pair. The presence of this `roles` is essentially the issue. It does not matter that the values there might match up to the `Required Scope` in the [Power BI REST Admin API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin). It was described to us as if there is a `roles` value in your access token then when the token is presented to the Power BI API the roles that are granted are attempted to be used, which ultimately results in a `PowerBINotAuthorizedException` because service principals are not allowed to use a certain role.

If you have an app that you have removed all permissions from, but still has a value coming through in your access token for the `roles` key/value pair, then I would suggest starting with a new app with no permissions allocated to it, and simply add the new app to the existing security group that you originally created. This is how we realized that this truly was the issue, and were then able to reconcile from there.

EDIT: Microsoft has now updated their API documentation on the relevant endpoints to reflect this information. For example, in [Admin - Groups GetGroupUsersAsAdmin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/groups-get-group-users-as-admin#required-scope) the **Required Scope** now reads:

> Tenant.Read.All or Tenant.ReadWrite.All
>
> Relevant only when authenticating via a standard delegated admin access token. Must not be present when authentication via a service principal is used.

Comment: I have created a new SPN, added it as an admin to the power bi premium workspace. This SPN has no permissions in API permissions section in Azure Portal. I am able to generate an access token but when I execute a DAX it says Unauthorized! Any help or working code snippet would be appreciated!

Comment: @Joseph that is likely unrelated to the problem here since it is outside of endpoints in the Admin API. A lot of the APIs outside of the Admin API have separate restrictions and permissions required, especially when it comes to SPN usage. You should check the documentation on the individual API enpoint for more details on what might cause that response.