# Get Token fo Power BI Rest Api in python

Tags: python, powerbi

Good afternoon everyone. I wrote the following code to get token for power bi rest api. And I seem to be getting a token. But when I try to request to get the list of the report, I consistently get a 401 error. How can I fix this? I thought msal solves this problem.

```
import msal
import requests
import json

client_id=client_id
client_secret=client_secret
authority_url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tennet_id'
scope = ["https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default"]

app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id,authority=authority_url,client_credential=client_secret)
result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)

if 'access_token' in result:
    access_token = result['access_token']
    header = {'Content-Type':'application/json','Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'}
    api_out = requests.get(url=url_groups, headers=header)
    print(api_out.json())
else:
    print(result.get("error"))
    print(result.get("error_description"))

group_id = group_id

url = f"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{group_id}/reports"

headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

I always reply and get a 401 error

Comment: Very similar question with a possible answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71001110/power-bi-rest-api-requests-not-authorizing-as-expected/71037810#71037810

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It was necessary to add an application to the workspace

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).